# Not able to access parent class variable in child class in kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In kotlin I am trying to use parent class variables in child class but I am not able to use them ,as I am new to kotlin I don't understand how to do it simply

I am trying to access sharedPerfernces and getting but its giving me null

```
class webViewActivity : AppCompatActivity{

 internal var shared_preferences: SharedPreferences? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        shared_preferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        mContext = this
    }


class JavaScriptInterface(private val mContext: Context) {

 @JavascriptInterface
        fun exampleGet(path: String): String {
            return webViewActivity().shared_preferences!!.getString(path, "")

//here shared_perferences is null 
        }
}



}
```

why I am not able to access parent class variables without constructor of parent class in child class . give me some suggestion ,little help will be appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `inner` before `JavaScriptInterface` class.

Just like that:

```
inner class JavaScriptInterface(private val mContext: Context) {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun exampleGet(path: String): String {
        return shared_preferences!!.getString(path, "")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ,by using inner I am able to access parent class variable , but still my kotlin activity is not working as my previous java activity

Comment: Please explain in details

Comment: ohh .. Its my mistake .working now .thanks for help